# Decorator: How to get original function variables

Tags: python

Given the following view function:

```
@validate_credentials
def validate_user(request):
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

How would I get the request.GET values in the wrapper?

```
def validate_credentials(view_function):
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        # request = ?
        return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_view
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether the function is called `validate_user(req)` or `validate_user(request=req)` it will be in `args` or `kwargs`, respectively. The following line will ensure that the argument (or `None`) is assigned to `request` in either case:

```
request = kwargs.get('request', args[0] if args else None)
```